# Not sure how to correctly include Scrollview in app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am having issues including a timer in my app. This is how my default app looks initially and below is the corresponding code

[image]

```
    return (
    <TopTab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        scrollEnabled: true,
      }}>
          <TopTab.Screen
            name="FIRST TAB"
            component={TabDashboardDetail}
            listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
          />
          <TopTab.Screen
            name="SECOND TAB"
            component={TabDashboardDetail}
            listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
          />
          <TopTab.Screen
            name="THIRD TAB"
            component={TabDashboardDetail}
            listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
          />
          <TopTab.Screen
            name="FOURTH TAB"
            component={TabDashboardDetail}
            listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
          />
          <TopTab.Screen
            name="FIFTH TAB"
            component={TabDashboardDetail}
            listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
          />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
)
```

Now the timer has to be included in the same file in which the above code is written. I tried to do that and below is how the app renders as well as its code. All the tab screens are not rendering due to including the timer. How do I resolve this?

[image]

```
    return (
    <ScrollView style={{flex:1, height: 50}}>
    <TopTab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        scrollEnabled: true,
      }}>
          <TopTab.Screen
            name="FIRST TAB"
            component={TabDashboardDetail}
            listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
          />
          <TopTab.Screen
            name="SECOND TAB"
            component={TabDashboardDetail}
            listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
          />
          <TopTab.Screen
            name="THIRD TAB"
            component={TabDashboardDetail}
            listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
          />
          <TopTab.Screen
            name="FOURTH TAB"
            component={TabDashboardDetail}
            listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
          />
          <TopTab.Screen
            name="FIFTH TAB"
            component={TabDashboardDetail}
            listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
          />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
    <View>
    <Text>
      {`${time.hours < 10 ? '0' + time.hours : time.hours} : ${time.minutes < 10 ? '0' + time.minutes : time.minutes} : ${time.seconds < 10 ? '0' + time.seconds : time.seconds}`}
    </Text>
  </View>
  </ScrollView>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think You should put TabView inside ScrollView.

and why did you gave ScrollView fix height of 50?

if timer is common in all screens then you can do this instead.

```
    return (
<>
<TopTab.Navigator
  tabBarOptions={{
    scrollEnabled: true,
  }}>
      <TopTab.Screen
        name="FIRST TAB"
        component={TabDashboardDetail}
        listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
      />
      <TopTab.Screen
        name="SECOND TAB"
        component={TabDashboardDetail}
        listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
      />
      <TopTab.Screen
        name="THIRD TAB"
        component={TabDashboardDetail}
        listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
      />
      <TopTab.Screen
        name="FOURTH TAB"
        component={TabDashboardDetail}
        listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
      />
      <TopTab.Screen
        name="FIFTH TAB"
        component={TabDashboardDetail}
        listeners={{ tabPress: e => console.log('Tab press', e.target), }}
      />
</TopTab.Navigator>
<Text>
  {`${time.hours < 10 ? '0' + time.hours : time.hours} : ${time.minutes < 10 ? '0' + time.minutes : time.minutes} : ${time.seconds < 10 ? '0' + time.seconds : time.seconds}`}
</Text>
  </>
)
```